# How to rename filename or folders with write.csv function in R

Tags: r, csv

This is how typically we write csv files inside R

```
write.csv(MyData, file = "/home/Eka/Folder/Data.csv")

Result
Data.csv
```

my question is can we pass a variable such that we can rename our filename with a variable name.

pseudocode.

```
$fname="EkaData"
write.csv(MyData, file = "/home/Eka/Folder/$fname.csv")

Result    
EkaData.csv
```

another question

how to create a folder with a variable name while using **write.csv**

eg:

```
$fname="EkaFolder"
write.csv(MyData, file = "/home/Eka/$fname/Data.csv")

Result    
/home/Eka/EkaFolder/Data.csv
```

Comment: Can't you just paste it as a string? `write.csv(MyData, file=paste("/home/Eka/Folder/", fname, ".csv", sep=""))`. And the same with folder.

Comment: Or use sprintf: `file=sprintf("/home/Eka/%s/Data.csv", fname)`

Comment: you can use `file.rename`

Comment: @Heroka i have tried `sprintf` it dosent create a folder with the variable name but can write file name

Comment: I think you need to create the folder outside write.csv.